# Updating ASP.NET Knowledge

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had done professional ASP.NET development in the 1.1 days, and was aware of debates that were soon to be settled in 2.0 (e.g. master pages versus page-inheritance).  Since then I've continued to use .net in-depth through 3.5, *except for my usage of ASP.NET*.

I'd like to know your choice of resources for getting caught up on ASP.NET (again).  Certainly I've already found some help:

- [ASP.NET 2.0 improvements](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/ASP.NET-2-0-Improvements.aspx)
- [New features in ASP.NET MVC 3.0](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/730_New_Features_in_ASP_NET_MVC_3_0_Preview_Part_1.aspx)
- [New features in ASP.NET 3.5](http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=42123)

I doubt these samples are complete, and I'd still be left wondering about "meta" facts of ASP.NET, such as "what are its shortcomings?"  "How has its age shown?"  "What ASP.NET techniques were hyped, but later proved to be a bust?"

If you know of articles or books that help answer all these questions, please share.

Comment: One option is to head to [www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) and skip through them rapidly until you spot something you don't immediately understand from your knowledge of earlier versions. Slow down, read that bit til you understand, and skip on again. Depending on how obsolete your experience is, you'll either be learning from scratch, or find yourself skipping entire chapters until you get to the advanced tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to look into:

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
[What's New in ASP.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e.aspx)
[Razor Syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) is very interesting as well and of course [ajax development](http://www.asp.net/ajax) has come a long way as well with tight integration to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).